# Prolog Maze: Lookup predicate

Tags: prolog, lookup, maze

I have a question:

How to do a lookup predicate for a maze.
Given a lab:

```
[[[down,left,up],[left,down,up],[right,up],[up],[,up],[right,left,up]],
[[left,down],[down,up],[down,up],[],[down],[right,down]],
[[left,up],[down,up],[down,up],[down],[down,up],[right,down,up]],
[[right,left],[left,up],[up],[up],[up],[right,up]],
[[left,down],[right,down],[left,down],[down],[down],[right,down]]]
```

I need define a way of looking up a cell in the Labryinth datastructure (Andrew Rice sugestion)

```
 lookup(Lab,(X,Y),Walls)
```

I already have the nth:

```
nth(1,[H|T],H).
nth(N,[_|T],R) :- M is N-1, nth(M,T,R).
```

Now my lookup:

```
lookup(Lab, (X, Y), Walls) :-
    nth(Y, Lab, R),
    nth(X, Lab, Y1),
```

Is this right?

EDIT!!!

My code:

```
nth(1,[H|_],H).
nth(N,[_|_],R) :- 
    M is N-1,
    nth(M,_,R).

lookup(Lab, (X, Y), Walls) :-
    Y1 is nth(Y, Lab, _),
    Y == Y1,
    X1 is nth(X, Lab, Y1),
    X1 == Walls.


calc(up,(X,Y1),(X,Y2)) :- 
    Y2 is Y1-1.
calc(down,(X,Y1),(X,Y2)) :- 
    Y2 is Y1+1.
calc(left,(X1,Y),(X2,Y)) :- 
    X2 is X1-1. 
calc(right,(X1,Y),(X2,Y)) :- 
    X2 is X1+1.

map_calc(_,[],[]).
map_calc((X,Y),[H|T],[(H,X1,Y1)|S]) :- 
    calc(H,(X,Y),(X1,Y1)),
    map_calc((X,Y),T,S).
```

My possible_moves:

```
movs_possiveis(Lab, (X,Y), Movs, Poss) :- 
lookup(Lab, (X,Y), Walls),
\+memberchk(Movs),
map_calc((X,Y), Walls, Poss).
```

Is this right?

Thanks

Comment: No, that is not right. `Y1 is nth(Y, Lab, R)` won't work at all. `is/2` is for arithmetic expression evaluation. `nth(Y, Lab, R)` is a predicate call, but not an arithmetic expression. `nth(Y, Lab, R)` is a relation that indicates `R` is the `Y`-th element of `Lab`. You should have at least gotten some error messages if you attempted your code.

Comment: So I to build lookup(Lab,(X,Y),Walls) which is true if the Yth element of Lab is Row and the Xth element of Row is Walls. If I change it to this, does it get better?

Comment: By the way, my nth is giving warnings saying that T and N are singleton variables

Comment: *Singleton variable* means a variable that appears once, so is serving no purpose for you as a named variable. It's not used anywhere else. In your new code you show, `R` and `Y1` are also singleton (unless there's more code after that you haven't shown). You can write `nth(1, [H|T], H).` as `nth(1, [H|_], H).` to get rid of the warning for that clause (you don't care what `T` is). `N` is not singleton the way you have it written in your problem. Check that what you wrote above is what you are actually running. By the way, Prolog already has an `nth0` and `nth1`. Why are you writing your own?

Comment: Thanks. No more errors. Yes, my teacher want us to do that, don't know why. By the way, now I need to build possible_moves. What I got so far.